# Reassigning keys in dictionary w.r.t another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python and having problem with the following task:

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
A_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 's', 2: 's', 3: 'r'**, 4: 'm', 5: 'm', 6: 'a', 7: 'k'}
```

I want to reassign the keys in A_dict with respect to the base_dict given as:

```
base_dict = {0: 'k', 1: 'm', 2: 'm', 3: 's', 4: 'a', 5: 's', 6: 'r', 7: 'r'}
```

The first value in `A_dict` is `r` and its key is 0. The key here should be assigned to the first key of `r` in `base_dict (0 -> 6)`. The second `r` in `A_dict` has a key 3; that should be assigned to the next key of `r` in `base_dict ( 3 -> 7)`. And so on with all the other values. There will always be more or equal number of each value in the `base_dict` than in `A_dict`.

I want to be able to get the following from the above inputs:

```
A_dict -> base_dict
0 -> 6
1 -> 3
2 -> 5
3 -> 7
4 -> 1
5 -> 2
6 -> 4
7 -> 0
```

I will be using the above relations to change positions of values in a matrix.

Sorry if my description is unclear. Can someone please point me the right direction?

All the best
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> A_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 's', 2: 's', 3: 'r', 4: 'm', 5: 'm', 6: 'a', 7: 'k'}
>>> base_dict = {0: 'k', 1: 'm', 2: 'm', 3: 's', 4: 'a', 5: 's', 6: 'r', 7: 'r'}
>>>
>>> d = sorted(base_dict)
>>> used = set()
>>> for key, value in sorted(A_dict.items()):
...     key2 = next((k for k in d if base_dict[k] == value and k not in used))
...     used.add(key2)
...     print('{} -> {}'.format(key, key2))
...
0 -> 6
1 -> 3
2 -> 5
3 -> 7
4 -> 1
5 -> 2
6 -> 4
7 -> 0
```

- used `sorted` becasue dictionary does not guarantee order.

Comment: This maps both 1 and 2 to 3. You should check whether the keys are already used.

Comment: @tobias_k, You're right. I fixed that. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will check what the function next() is doing to fully understand.